# After merge of release branch, why is master 1 commit ahead of develop?

Tags: git, git-flow

I am still new to this so I am trying to understand why `master` ends up 1 commit ahead of `develop` instead of the same after merging a `release` branch back into `develop` and `master`.

My `develop` branch was 5 commits ahead of master, then I created a `release` branch and tagged which was also 5 commits ahead of `master`, then I merged `release` branch back into `develop` and `master` but `master` ends up 1 commit ahead of `develop`.

Is this because no changes were made to the `release` branch and it was the same as `develop` so the merge didn't create a commit on `develop` but it did on `master` which makes `master` 1 commit ahead even though `master` and `develop` now are the same at this point?

Is this ok? Will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is that the merge commit is being detected. Your commit history probably looks something like this:

```
*------------------ A [master]
 \                 /
  *---*---*---*---B [develop,release]
```

Commit `B` is, as you mention, 5 commits ahead of `master`. When you merged the release branch back into `master`, this created a merge commit, `A`. That merge commit does not yet exist in `develop`.

This is not something that you need to worry about, because the merge commit doesn't contain any changes itself, it only merges the two histories together. Normally, that commit will automatically end up in `develop` next time you finish a `hotfix` branch anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just merge `master` back into develop instead of `release`?

Comment: @Bas: Not sure what you mean by the latter part of your comment (`release` was merged into `master`, not `develop`). There isn't really any need to merge `master` back into `develop`, because the only thing that `develop` is missing is the merge commit (but `develop` already has all the changes contained in the merge commit).

Comment: Why is a hotfix branch useful in this scenario?

Comment: @jmng: What do you mean?  I didn't say it was useful, just noted that the merge commit will end up in `develop` eventually since the OP is using [tag:git-flow].

Comment: You mentioned that "Normally, that commit will automatically end up in develop next time you finish a hotfix branch.", I had the same question as the OP ("what about that extra merge commit on master and not on develop") so I was confused when you mentioned a hotfix in order for the merge commit to end up in develop; why is the hotfix needed/related?

Comment: @jmng: I've edited my answer to clarify a bit.  It doesn't matter that there is (temporarily) a commit in `master` that isn't in `develop`, because the commit doesn't contain any changes other than merging the two histories.  [tag:git-flow] is set up to have both `master` and `develop` be long-running branches, so while functionally `develop` will be ahead of `master`, it's okay for `master` to have an extra commit.

Comment: @jmng: To answer your direct question, a hotfix is based off `master`, and merges into both `master` and `develop`.  So when the hotfix is completed, its history, including the last merge commit, will now be in `develop`.

Comment: OK, now I understand, thanks for clarifying :) If I may ask: if nothing happens to justify an hotfix, is there a standard/safer way of assuring that the merge commit is propagated to develop, to avoid the difference between master and develop? I'm actually afraid to try this on Eclipse/egit and end up with the usual rejected-non-fast-forward mess :P

Comment: @jmng: Aside from a hotfix, you could just merge `master` into `develop`.  But there is really no need, because while the commits differ, the *contents* of `master` and `develop` are both the same since the `release` branch started at `develop` and was merged into `master` already.

Comment: No guarantee you would ever do a hotfix, we have a repo who's master is 2,300+ commits ahead of develop. There should be a setting to omit these commits from the difference (if there is I'd love to know). Unless develop is a copy of master these branches will always be at least 1 commit different in their history. In 2023 I still actively dislike this feature.

Comment: I take it back, it's a feature of the merge type we're doing. I'm no longer put out by it :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752967/prevent-master-branch-from-being-ahead-of-dev

Answer (score -1):

IMO that 1 commit ahead is compared to origin/master or the remote branch your master is tracking. Since you have do a merge on local branch, it will create a new commit for that merge on your local master, therefore makes it 1 commit ahead.

Comment: I just always thought that development should be ahead of Master at all times?

Comment: When I merged the release to master and develop I only see a commit to master, is this because there were no changes to the release after it was made and was at the same point as develop? I agree with your statement the commit is done to the local master and pushed to origin, even on the remote branches develop is now 1 commit behind master. I normally don't create release and feature branches as I am a solo developer, I have just been merging develop into master on the remote server. I would like to change that practice though because it seems wrong to do.

Comment: 1.It is normal. 2. I still think ahead/behind is talking about local branch vs remote branch.. so N/A. 3.Yes for the question. And for the best practice part honestly I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Now you have to Fast-Foward develop into master to have master and develop in the same level

Comment: While a fast-forward merge of `master` into `develop` would technically solve the "problem", it is unnecessary (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689080/2747593)), and is not recommended by the standard [tag:git-flow] branching model.