# Prevent Master Branch from being ahead of dev

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, git-workflow

we got a pretty standard git workflow, but i am annoyed by one thing: The master is ahead of development because every deployment we create a merge-commit from dev to master.

At first our workflow:

- `master branch` - always clean and available for a deployment
- `development branch` - Collects new features / bug fixes if those are
  reviewed and approved
- `feature branch` - a new branch that only has
  needed changes for one feature (**it is branched off `development
  branch`**)

Every successfull pull request (feature > development) creates a **merge-commit**, which is fine.

But every deployment (development > master) also creates a **merge-commit** which only exists in the master. So what happens is that after 20 deployments the master branch is 20 commits ahead of development branch.

How do you deal with that behaviour? Do you merge master > dev from time to time (which actually does nothing but creating a useless merge-commit)?

rebasing development-branch seems not to be an option because then every developer would lose the tracked remote branch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're asking for is called a "fast forward" merge. Since you mention pull-requests, I assume you're using something to manage your branches for you (GitHub, BitBucket, etc.), so the exact instructions to accomplish what you want may vary.

---

Given this state:

```
master o-o-o-o
              \
development    o-o-o
```

Your software likely is applying the `--no-ff` flag when merging (which is standard behavior because you want the merge commit when merging a feature into `development`). From the command line this is equivalent to:

`git merge --no-ff development`

```
master o-o-o-o-------o
              \     /
development    o-o-o
```

However, if you want to avoid the merge commit you DO want to fast-forward the branch:

`git merge --ff development` (The `--ff` should be unnecessary because it is the default behavior)

```
master/development o-o-o-o-o-o-o
```

---

Notes:

1. If you do this, you lose the ability to see when `development` was merged into `master`. This may not be a concern (or you may be addressing that in another way, such as with tags).
2. If you do have unique commits on `master` and a fast-forward is not possible, this will still create a merge-commit. However, you can use the flag `--ff-only` to error out if a fast-forward is not possible (either unique commits in `master` or already up-to-date).

Comment: what an awesome explanation, thanks a lot for that!! 

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in [the presentation of GitFlow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), `master` is a branch that is always a merge target, never a source. Thus, as you correctly observed, `master` branch will contain merge commits that no other branch has. That's no problem at all, and at most a cosmetic issue.

Why are you annoyed by this? If you stick to the flow, you will have these commits, but why even care about them? They don't affect the workflow in any way.

Comment: the annoying thing is that git always shows the dev branch as "20 commits behind, 40 commits ahead"

thats not the most intuitive thing. and IF we have a hotfix directly in master you couldn't tell that it's missing in dev.

Comment: Where does it show it that way? I only know that type of message from comparisons between a branch and its' upstream, and you wouldn't set master as an upstream for your local develop?! As for the hotfix: Whoever merges it to master should cherry-pick it to develop right away.

Answer (score 1):

That's how we do it: Branch a `release` branch from `development` when you think your features are ready ("code drop"). Run expensive tests there and fix the bugs, then merge `release` to `master`, and merge `master` back to `development`. Start a new `release` branch again.

You can merge `master` back to `development` after each deployment, too, but without any real changes in the `release` branch, that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

We have 3 base branch develop, staging & master. Whatever new feature we build we save in feature/branch & pull changes in develop. Since this feature needs testing so it will be pulled again in Staging branch. On getting sign off from tester we push it to master branch. In comparison to your workflow we have less commit to master branch, but again merge conflict will be still there if you have made any changes in pre-existing code.

Comment: Your answer should address the question: 'How do you deal with that behaviour?`, rather than suggest another workflow, which the poster may not be able to follow.